# Laravel | Return rows in order based off pivot

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following setup:

stages:

`| id | name | order |`

commands:

```
| id | name   | body         |
------------------------------=
| 1  | test   | phpunit      |
| 2  | style  | echo "style" |
| 3  | deploy | deploy       |
```

command_stage:

```
| command_id | stage_id | order |
---------------------------------
| 1          | 1        | 1     |
| 2          | 2        | 1     |
| 3          | 1        | 2     |
```

Basically, I would like to create a method on the stage model which allows me to get all of the commands back based off of the order, but commands have a specific order and so do the stages.

So each command is stored under a stage so we know which part to run but each command also has an order in that stage. Now I know I can do something like the following:

```
$inOrder = collect();

Stage::get()->each(function ($stage) {
    $commands = $stage->commands()->orderByPivot('order')->get();

    $inOrder->push($commands);
});

return $inOrder;
```

But I was wondering if there is a nicer way to do this? Or even a way to do this solely on one database hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-load and sort the relationship:

```
$stages = Stage::with(['commands' => function ($subQuery) { 
  $subQuery->orderBy('command_stage', 'order');
}])->get();

foreach($stages as $stage) {
  $inOrder->push($stage->commands);
}
```

This method of Eager-Loading will reduce the N+1 query issue of doing `$stage->commands()` inside the `foreach()` loop.

Comment: This looks good but why not directly query commands with first order by stage and then second order by order, this way you directly get sorted collection and don't the foreach loop

Comment: ^ That's a fair point on adjusting query logic, I was simply adapting the current solution to be more efficient. If all Stages are being loaded anyway, then a direct query against Commands, join and sorted via Stages should work the same. I'd add that comment as an answer if you've got the time :)